# How can I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[This thread](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22215/events-that-dont-arrive) about our experience of time was met with gasps of confusion and amazement. Or at least a few downvotes.

I say there :

> I am just trying to state the commonly held conception that our
>   experience of time is also a time. Which of course does not include
>   death

This makes so much sense to me that I am amazed and confused by the response.

My question is: how can I make myself any clearer than this?

Comment: We can't answer this if we don't understand what you mean in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me to say "our experience of time is also a time". You'll have to explain that, start by defining "time". With regard to the question you link, it is unclear because you keep going back and forth with what you are suggesting (events don't arrive getting closer, but wait they do, don't they? etc.). Even if you were, the question is not grounded in philosophy enough to be a good fit; we like questions that reference specific expertise rather than simply generate a long list of opinions.

Comment: "Even if you were, the question is not grounded in philosophy enough to be a good fit" where is the close option for this ??

Comment: "**primarily opinion-based** - Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."